# How do we determine region type for double integral if we have a pair of complex function bound?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOadv.jpg)

Question above is just a simple example that it's easy to integrate if we draw a graph. However, what should we solve double integral if we don't have such a graphical display.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of $\iint_D fdA$, where $f$ is a $0$-form $R^2 $->$R$ defined on some region D $\epsilon$ $R^2$, is fundamentally geometric. Therefore, it is generally helpful to simply draw a sketch of the region D when solving these sorts of problems. This should not be too difficult to do in $R^2$.